# extracting strings using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings:

1. LOW QUALITY PROTEIN: cysteine proteinase 5-like [Solanum pennellii]
2. PREDICTED: LOW QUALITY PROTEIN: uncharacterized protein LOC107059219 [Solanum pennellii]
3. XP_019244624.1 PREDICTED: peroxidase 40-like [Nicotiana attenuata]
4. RVW92024.1 Retrovirus-related Pol polyprotein from transposon TNT 1-94 [Vitis vinifera]
5. hypothetical protein VITISV_035070 [Vitis vinifera]

How to extract the below strings from the above strings?

1. cysteine proteinase 5-like
2. uncharacterized protein LOC107059219
3. peroxidase 40-like
4. Retrovirus-related Pol polyprotein from transposon TNT 1-94
5. hypothetical protein VITISV_035070

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem don't need regex. I would prefer following solution because it is easy to understand

```py
st = "PREDICTED: LOW QUALITY PROTEIN: uncharacterized protein LOC107059219 [Solanum pennellii]"
st.split(":")[-1].split("[")[0].strip()
```

Comment: It seems it failed with `s="RVW92024.1 Retrovirus-related Pol polyprotein from transposon TNT 1-94 [Vitis vinifera]"` because it does not remove `RVW92024.1`